# Itertools groupby dynamic iteration of itertools._grouper object

Tags: python, iterator, python-itertools

Consider this Data which consists [date, sales amount, # of sales]:

```
data=[[datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,2,0,0), 14, 3],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,3,0,0), 15, 5],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,5,0,0), 11, 4],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,1,0,0), 18, 7],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,5,0,0), 14, 1],]
```

What I am doing is grouping the data by date and performing weighted average on basis of the data.
The weighted average function takes nested array and spits out a single value:

```
def weighted_average(nested_array):
    # data format[[14,3], [15,5], [11,4]]
    # performs weighted average
    return weighted_average
```

Grouping of data is done in following manner.

```
grouped_sales = itertools.groupby(data, date_key)
```

I calculate the aggregated values as follows:

```
aggregate_sales = (
(day, weighted_average([day_sales,sales] for date, day_sales, sales in week_sales))
for day, week_sales in grouped_sales)
```

Note that in case above, I know that week_sales(itertools._grouper) object contains 3 values (date, date_sales, sales) and I easily iterate on them.
What if the I don't know how many values an itertool._grouper object contains to iterate on..
Let me explain..

The problem starts here. At times I have Sales data of multiple items like [date, sales amount of item 1, # of sales of item 1, sales amount of item 2, # of sales of item 2, ...]:

```
data=[(datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,2,0,0), 14, 3, 55, 2],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,3,0,0), 15, 5, 68, 3],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,1,5,0,0), 11, 4, 42, 1],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,1,0,0), 18, 7, 22, 2],
[datetime.datetime(2012,1,2,5,0,0), 14, 1, 97, 5],]
```

So the length of nested array in data array is variable.

How can I iterate over the itertools._grouper object(week_sales) which now contains 5 values (which may be variable in my case) and take weighted average of each item in pairs?

Comment: So, do you want to modify `weighted_average` to handle iterator of arbitrary-length lists?

Comment: `def weighted_average(L): return sum(L[i]*L[i+1] for i in range(0,len(L),2))/(len(L)/2)`

Comment: I want to know how to iterate arbitrary-length itertools._grouper object so that I can pass the numeric values to my weighted average function..